# PHP Loop Through CSV and Print Selected Row

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display a CSV file in a browser and print the selected (via radio button) row.

Here's my code to print the CSV file (with a radio button next to each row):

```
<?php

echo "<html><body><table border='1'>";

$f = fopen("data.csv", "r");
$row = 1;
echo "<form method='post' action='submit.php'>";
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
   $to_print = implode(",", $line);  // added this and changed value below (to use it)
   echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='env[$row]' value='$to_print' /></td>";
   foreach ($line as $cell) {
      echo "<td contenteditable='true'>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>\n";
   ++$row;
}

fclose($f);
echo "</table><br><Input type='submit'></form></span></body></html>";

?>
```

I have a submit button at the bottom that (when clicked) should pass the data in the selected row to submit.php which should print it.

Here's the submit.php:

```
<?php

echo "<html><body>";

print_r($_POST);  // this prints what I need

if (! empty($_POST['env'])) {
    $j=0;
    foreach ($_POST['env'] as $env) {
        // Can't get anything to print in here
        ++$j;
    }
}

echo "</body></html>";

?>
```

But it prints nothing. I'm guessing it has something to do with the 'value' of my radio button:

```
value='<?php echo $line;?>]'
```

That can't be right...

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `$line` is an array. If you want to echo it as a whole `implode()` it first. And you will get the column names first.

Comment: Your post name is more than `env`

Comment: Okay I added an implode (edited above) to my submit and still nothing... any other suggestions?

Comment: view your page source and post that.

Comment: May I suggest you avoid using echo for spitting out HTML as much as possible.    ... ?> <tr><td><input type='radio' name='<? echo env[$row]; ?>' value='<? echo $line; ?>' /></td> ... It will make your HTML structure mode readable.

Comment: You can not have `form` as child element of `table`, that’s invalid HTML. Put the former around the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is this line:

`echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='env[<?php echo $row;?>]'`

You are echoing some HTML from within PHP. Inside the line your are echoing out, **you are opening `<?php` tags again**. Debugging what is being POSTed, you are actually just sending the string "<?php echo $row;?>"

To fix this issue, change your echo line to this:

`echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='env[$row]'` ...

As long as you are using double quotes, the `$row` variable will be interpreted and you'll get the outcome that you want.

Edit:

Once you have the data output to the page correctly, you need to reconsider how you are looping over the data.

The value of `$line` is set by `[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)` which returns an array. You are setting this array as the value to the input like this: `value=$line`, but seeing as `$line` is an array, PHP is making an array-to-string conversion, and you're not getting what you expect.

Solution: Either pick a single index of the array to set as value (such as `$value=$line[0]`) or output the `td` within the inner loop, where you are looping over each field within the row.

Comment: Okay I changed that (edited above)... now I see that my row is being properly passed to the submit... but it's still not printing anything.  Yet, if I add a print_r($_POST); to the top of my submit, I can see that my values are being passed.  Does something need to be changed in the submit? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using `$value=$line[0]` did work to print a single column. But I need the whole row... I updated my code above with comments.  Almost there... just need to find a way to access the array in my submit loop. Thanks again!